# Receive file via websocket and save/write to local folder

Tags: websocket

Our application is entirely built on websockets. We don't do any HTTP request-reply. However, we are stuck with file download. If i receive file content via websockets can I wrote to local folder on user computer ?

If it makes a difference, we are only supporting Chrome so not issue if it doesn't work on other browsers.

Also, I know i can do this via HTTP. Trying to avoid it and stick to websockets since thats how the entire app is.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on size of your file.

If size is less than about 50 MB, I would encode file's content to base64 string on the server and send this string to the client. Client should receive parts of the string, concat them to single result, and store. After receiving whole string, add link (tag `<a>`) to your page with attribute `href` set to `"data:<data_type>;base64,<base64_encoded_file_content>"`. `<data_type>` is a mime type of your file, for example "text/html" or "image/png". Suggest file name by adding `download` attribute set to name of file (doesn't work for Chrome on OS X).

Unfortunately I have no solution for large files. Currently there is only FileEntry API that allows to write files with JS, but according to documentation it is supported only by Chrome v13+, learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileEntry.