# How can I show feedbacks to users while downloading from SFTP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

## I have

a download button when clicking on it, it takes about 15 seconds to download a file because it has to SFTP into the server, find the right path/files, and return response **download**.

[image]

## HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-primary btn-download-1" onclick="startDownload('1')"><i class="fa fa-download "></i></a>
```

***Note*** : where 1 is the key for me to know which file it is ...

---

## Right now

the button just will trigger this **function** below

```
function startDownload(interfaceId) {
    window.location = "/nodes/interface/capture/download?port=" + interfaceId;
    console.log(interfaceId);
}
```

It basically refreshes the page and call that download route

**/nodes/interface/capture/download**

```
public function download_files()
{

    $dir = '';
    $portNumber = Request::get('port');
    $zipMe = false;

    $remotePath = "/home/john/logs/".$dir."/";

    if (!isset($dir) || $dir == null) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withFlashDanger('SFTP Could not connect.');
    }

    $acsIp =  explode('://', env('ACS_URL'));
    $acsIp =  explode(':',$acsIp[1])[0];
    $sftp = new SFTP($acsIp.':22');

    if (!$sftp->login('john', '***')) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withFlashDanger('SFTP Could not connect.');
    }


    // Get into the Specified Directory
    $sftpConn = Storage::disk('sftp');

    $SFTPFiles = $sftpConn->allFiles('/'.$dir);

    if ( count($SFTPFiles) > 0 ) {
        foreach ($SFTPFiles as $file) {
            $fileName = $file;
            break;
        }

    } else {
        \Log::info('Files Not found in the Remote!');
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withFlashDanger('Files Not found in the Remote!');
    }

    // Create and give 777 permission to remote-files directory
    if (!is_dir(public_path('remote-files/'.$dir))) {
        mkdir(public_path('remote-files/'.$dir), 0777, true);
    }

    $filesToZip = [];

    foreach ( $SFTPFiles as $fileName ) {
        if ( $fileName == '..' || $fileName == '.' ) {
            continue;
        } else if ( $fileName == '' ) {
            \Log::info('File not found');
            continue;
        }

        $fileName     = explode("/", $fileName);
        $onlyFileName = (!empty($fileName) && isset($fileName[1])) ? $fileName[1] : "";
        $filepath = $remotePath.$onlyFileName;

        if (strpos($onlyFileName , $portNumber) !== false) {


            // Download the remote file at specified location in Local
            if (!$sftp->get($filepath, 'remote-files/'.$dir.'/'.$onlyFileName))
            {
                die("Error downloading file ".$filepath);
            }

            $file = public_path('remote-files/'.$dir.'/').$onlyFileName;

            $headers = array(
                'Content-Description: File Transfer',
                'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
                'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"',
                'Cache-Control: must-revalidate',
                'Pragma: public',
                'Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)
            );

            return Response::download($file, $onlyFileName, $headers);

        }

        // IF File is exists in Directory
        if ( file_exists( public_path('remote-files/'.$dir.'/').$onlyFileName ) ) {

            $filesToZip[] = public_path('remote-files/'.$dir.'/').$onlyFileName;
            \Log::info('File Generated '.'remote-files/'.$dir.'/'.$onlyFileName);


            // Remove Files from public/remote-files
            $this->removeDirAndFiles('', public_path('remote-files/'.$dir));
            exit;


        } else {
            \Log::info('File not Generated '.'remote-files/'.$dir.'/'.$onlyFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

## Result

It is working, but somehow, it stays there for 15 seconds without any sort of feedback. It's really bad, users have no idea what is going on.

I want to show a modal say *"Downloading is in progress, please don't close the window"*, but I don't know how to do that since it is mandatory for my to use a GET to download a file.I'm kind of stuck now.

## Any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the delay is at the server side, I believe you can do two ways:

1. Have a route to create queue jobs and determine what is the progress, and another route for user to download a downloaded files in server. The user will ping to the first route every second to determine status.

   The idea is to generate a unique ID each time a session is created, store it in an Array that is shared by both `download_files()` route and another to initiate `download_files()` and store its result.

   Example:

   ```
   $global_progress = array();
   $global_files = array();

   public function checkup_progress($id = null) {
       if ($id == null) {
           // this is new request, create job here
           $id = generate_id_func();
           download_file_job($id);
       } else if ($global_progress[$id] != "FINISHED") {
           // return $global_progress[$id] result
       } else {
           // finished, return download link
           // return route to "link_to_download_file/$id"
       }
   }

   public function download_file_job($id) {
       $global_progress[$id] = "NEW";
       // some code
       $global_progress[$id] = "IN PROGRESS (1)";
       // more code
       // more state here
       $global_files[$id] = $file;
       $global_progress[$id] = "FINISHED";
   }

   public function link_to_download_file($id) {
       // code here
       return Response::download($file, $onlyFileName, $headers);
   }
   ```
2. If you dont want to change anything, you can use websocket that will update download state after few operations, and send files to the client. But this would be [restricted by the filesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166643/receive-file-via-websocket-and-save-write-to-local-folder) as websocket are handled in javascript, which means download must be stored javascript object in browser memory first.

Answer (score 0):

Show an [overlay div](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_overlay.asp) that has a message of your choosing, before doing the redirect. This requires nothing to be done on the server side.

```
function startDownload(interfaceId) {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block"; // Show the overlay
    window.location = "/nodes/interface/capture/download?port=" + interfaceId;
    console.log(interfaceId);
}
```

CSS

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 2; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer on hover */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: yellow;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div id="overlay">
  Downloading is in progress, please don't close the window
</div>
```